# MSOCAF Verification - Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class

Tags: c#, pinvoke, code-analysis

Hello guy's i have this error in MSOCAF :

> Because it is a P/Invoke method,
>   'CompoundDocument.CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(IntPtr, bool, out
>   CompoundDocument.ILockBytes)' should be defined in a class named
>   NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods, or UnsafeNativeMethods

I create a new class NativeMethods and move my P/Invoke in this class. But when i'm trying to call my P/Invoke i have an error :

Error   3

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'OfficeOpenXml.Utils.NativeMethods.CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(System.IntPtr,
>   bool, out OfficeOpenXml.Utils.ILockBytes)' has some invalid
>   arguments D:\TFS\L0449745\MSOCAF PUR-Contracts\Source
>   code\PUR-Contracts\Total.SharePoint.PUR-Contracts.ImportJob\Total.SharePoint.PUR-Contracts.ImportJob\Excel\Utils\CompoundDocument.cs  60  24  Total.SharePoint.PUR-Contracts.ImportJob

and

Error   4

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'out
>   OfficeOpenXml.Utils.CompoundDocument.ILockBytes' to 'out
>   OfficeOpenXml.Utils.ILockBytes'   D:\TFS\L0449745\MSOCAF
>   PUR-Contracts\Source
>   code\PUR-Contracts\Total.SharePoint.PUR-Contracts.ImportJob\Total.SharePoint.PUR-Contracts.ImportJob\Excel\Utils\CompoundDocument.cs  60  87  Total.SharePoint.PUR-Contracts.ImportJob

This is the class NativeMethods :

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern int CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(
        IntPtr hGlobal,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool fDeleteOnRelease,

        out ILockBytes ppLkbyt);
}
```

And the code when i call my P/Invoke :

```
 ILockBytes lb;
        var iret = NativeMethods.CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(IntPtr.Zero, true, out lb);

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(doc.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(doc, 0, buffer, doc.Length);
        UIntPtr readSize;
        lb.WriteAt(0, buffer, doc.Length, out readSize);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```

Thanks for answers !

Comment: You have two definitions of ILockBytes in different namespaces.  Delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem appears to be error 4. It states an incompatibility between:

```
OfficeOpenXml.Utils.CompoundDocument.ILockBytes
```

and

```
OfficeOpenXml.Utils.ILockBytes
```

So clearly one of these types was used to declare `CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal`, and a different type was used to declare the variable that you pass when calling `CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal`. You need to decide which of these two types to use, and stick to that single type.

You have other errors with your declaration, as covered in your other question. The return value is an `HRESULT` which maps to `int`. It is not a boolean, remove the return value attribute. The boolean parameter needs no `MarshalAs` either. Default marshalling is correct.